# Change point detection PELT

Tags: python, time-series

How can I get the value for optimal penalty when using the PELT algorithm for change point detection
For the below picture, it requires a penalty of 30 and the dataset is of length 315 samples:
[image]

The mean and standard deviation is as follows:

[image]

For the second sample, it requires a penalty with range of 4 to 14 with 90 samples:
The red marker indicated the point of split. the signal has a mean of 26.8 and std deviation of 7.9.
[image]

From this, is there some formula to calculate the penalty value for pelt algorthm from ruptures library?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, the most common choice of penalty is one which is linear in the number of changepoints. Examples of such penalties include Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) (`β = 2p`) and Schwarz Information Criterion (SIC, also known as BIC) (`β = p log n`).

You can simply use `pen = p * log(len(data))`, which `p` is used for calibration and `data` is an array of data values.

My suggestion is to define some levels of sensitivity for the algorithm by setting different penalty values.

```
def calculate_penalty(data, sensitivity, cal=[6, 3, 1.5]):
    if sensitivity == "Low":
        return cal[0] * log(len(data))
    elif sensitivity == "Medium":
        return cal[1] * log(len(data))
    elif sensitivity == "High":
        return cal[2] * log(len(data))
```

---

See [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.sigpro.2019.107299) and [this](https://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/html/10.11648.j.ajtas.20150406.30.html) articles for detailed explanations and more complex penalties.

Answer (score 0):

Model selection criterion is different in a model with change point compared to a general statistical model. @smrachi was correct about the general usage of penalties include AIC and BIC. However, in the change point detection schemes, the location of the change points should also be considered as parameters. Thus the total number of parameters is actually `p * (k + 1) + k` where `p` is the number of parameters for each segment and `k` is the number of change points.

Thus using BIC, the *total* penalty should be `(p * (k + 1) + k) * log(n) / 2` if the cost function is negative log likelihood. Thus in each segment, the penalty should be approximately `(p + 1) * log(n) / 2`.[1] A modified BIC can also be used where the penalty for each segment is `(p + 2) * log(n) / 2`.[2]

AIC tends to over estimate the number of change points in this setting and thus not generally used.

[1]: Zhang, Xianyang, and Trisha Dawn. "Sequential Gradient Descent and Quasi-Newton’s Method for Change-Point Analysis." International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics. PMLR, 2023.

[2]: Zhang, Nancy R., and David O. Siegmund. "A modified Bayes information criterion with applications to the analysis of comparative genomic hybridization data." Biometrics 63.1 (2007): 22-32.